# Crear función REDONDEAR igual a la de excel en lenguaje Swift 4

Tags: swift, double, redondeo

Estoy tratando de crear una función que haga un redondeo con un número de decimales que yo le especifique igual a la `FUNCIÓN REDONDEAR()` que tiene EXCEL en Swift 4.

Actualmente uso la función:

```
String(format:"%.2f",valorDouble)
```

pero ahora tengo un inconveniente porque esa función me retorna un String y yo necesito hacer más cálculos con el calor redondeado, por lo que necesito que la función me retorne un Double.
También intenté convertir el string que me retorna la función:

```
String(format:"%.2f",valorDouble) a Double
```

pero me devuelve otra vez con muchos decimales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo esta extensión; lo que haces es de acuerdo al número de decimales que quieres obtener el valor de 10 se eleva a esa potencia para luego hacer el cálculo de multiplicar y dividir por ese mismo valor.

```
extension Double {
    func roundNumber(with decimalNumbers: Int) -> Double {
        let res = pow(10.0, Double(decimalNumbers))
        
        return (self * res).rounded() / res
    }
}
```

Luego llamas a esa función desde el número:

```
let x = 12.334.roundNumber(with: 1)
let y = 3.14151629.roundNumber(with: 4)
print(x)//12.3
print(y)//3.1415
```

Haciendo una operación de suma:

```
let num1 = 12.131415.roundNumber(with: 4)
let num2 = 1.000133.roundNumber(with: 4)

let result = (num1 + num2).roundNumber(with: 4)
print(result)//13.1315
unLabel.text = String(result)//13.1315
```

Comment: Al imprimir si lo muestra redondeado con 2 decimales pero cuando veo el valor de la variable tiene muchos decimales 0 y termino con un 4 o 5 o cualquier otro número haciendo que se pierda la precisión de los centavos.

Comment: Si haces alguna operación matemática con `x`, `y` debes llamar nuevamente a la función. Acabo de hacer una suma y el resultado en un label se visualiza correctamente.